# Node stream bypassed pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, base64, gzip

I'm trying to consume the response of an HTTPs endpoint in node.
 The response data is a `json` encoded in `base64` and compressed in `gzip`.
This is how I'm doing it:

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
const base64 = require('base64-stream');
. . .
const options = {
    hostname: '',
    port: 443,
    path: '/api/1/endpoint',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body)
    }
}
const request = https.request(options);
request.on('response', (response) => {
  output = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
  // this is how I handle the response
  response.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(base64.decode()).pipe(output);
}
request.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
// write data to request body
request.write(body);
request.end();
```

The problem is that the output file is not fully decompressed, first part is json and the remaining is gzip binary:

```
     "id" : "4"
}, {
  "id" : "18"
} ],
"id" : "0048598-001",
"version" : 2228230,
"name" : "name-01- isи????????̸??(???????ф????(???????ѕ????Q??%????԰(???????ѕ???Ј?耉?????????Ʌ????̈?(???????х???耉?ɽ???(????????ɕ?ѕ???耈???ܴ?????P????????h??(????????ɕ?ѕ?    䈀耉????ͅ??ɼ???Ʌ?????????????(???????????ѕ???耈?????Դ??P????????h??(???????????ѕ?    䈀耉????
```

Now if I remove the `base64` decoding from the pipe (i.e. `pipe(base64.decode())`) I get a big `base64` line (i.e. the decompression went successfully) that I can decode from the CLI with the `base64` command.

```
response.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(output);
```

Any idea why the processing stopped and the rest of the stream went as is to the output?

Comment: By "feeling" I'd say you'd need to pass an `encoding` argument somewhere - I suppose that should go to the base64 decode argument. Do you know what's the character after `"is"`, the one that resolved as `и`?

Comment: @MichałKapracki it's a `t` here is the whole value `name-01- ist. med. fis.`

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example?

Comment: @MarkAdler I'm afraid I cannot, the endpoint is a private one, but if I can trying this if you have suggestions.

Comment: Then at least provide the binary portion of the result excerpt in hexadecimal. We can't figure anything out from и????????̸??(...

Comment: Agree, the `name.slice(100).toString(16)` would be good.

Comment: so what you're saying is there is a problem with the data? but then why it's working when I use the `base64` command line. Also, I tried to print the hex for each character of this `name` but nothing unusual with `for(i =0; i< name.length; i++) {console.log(name.charAt(i), name.charAt(i).toString(16))}`